# Array argument in awk function

Tags: awk

I have the following example in awk, consisting of a function and a body.  I am struggling with how arrays actually work inside functions.  Because although `array` is defined in function `changeit` and set to some value, in the body of the script one is using the name `a`.

I was under the impression that arrays are global, and the same name must be used in the body as well as within the function.

Although the array itself is made available for direct manipulation by the function, why does the body use a different name `a` rather than `array` ?

```
function changeit(array, ind, nvalue)
{
     array[ind] = nvalue
}

BEGIN {
    a[1] = 1; a[2] = 2; a[3] = 3
    changeit(a, 2, "two")
    printf "a[1] = %s, a[2] = %s, a[3] = %s\n",
            a[1], a[2], a[3]
}
```

Comment: So, uh, what is the question?  Your example code seems to do exactly what it indends, giving output of `a[1] = 1, a[2] = two, a[3] = 3`.

Comment: the sample you have copied is from the https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pass-By-Value_002fReference.html. didn't you read the context before it?

Comment: Yes, the manual says that the array itself is made available for direct manipulation by the function. But a different name is being used.

Comment: Aren't you surprised that `ind` and `nvalue` are never used outside of the function? They are [formal parameters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/formal_parameter). So is `array`. Later `a`, `2` and `"two"` are [actual parameters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/actual_parameter#English). This is not an answer because it's not clear what your question is (there is no question in your "question").

Comment: The names used in a function declaration (e. g. `func( param1, param2)` define the names that can be used _within the scope of that function_.  So `param1` and `param2` could be referenced within the code defining the function `func`.  Is that what you are asking after?

Comment: I thought that because arrays in awk are set globally, the same name must be used.

Comment: Arrays in awk are not set globally. A function may declare an additional arg which is not passed in, is used only in the function, whose name scope is only inside the function, and which is deleted when the function exits.

Comment: So it is like passing by reference in C.  Although wtah is declared in the body is global.  Right?

Comment: There are no separate declarations in awk. A variable is created by having a value assigned to it. An array variable is created by the first assignment to any of its elements. Inside a function body, all the names declared are local to that function, but their initializers are any corresponding values set in each function call. Any other variable name (whether referenced inside a function or not) is global. It is perfectly valid to have several functions use a global name that is not referenced anywhere in the "body", although I take care not to obfuscate my code in that way.

Comment: Since you don't know how function arguments work, there's probably a lot of other things you don't know about and so I recommend you get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and read through that to avoid any upcoming confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The args to an awk function (and in most other languages) are positional. So there is a one-to-one correspondence between `array` and `a`, `ind` and `2`, `nvalue` and `"two"`, for this *particular* function call.

That is clearly necessary for the `ind` and `nvalue` args, because `2` and `"two"` are not names, so the function cannot refer to them.

Just as important, but not so obvious: it would be extremely inconvenient to have a function that could only operate on a specific argument by name. Having a name for the arg means the function can operate on different arrays: `changeit (b, 7, "this")`.

There is an awk feature which is slightly unusual. The function can define more arguments than the caller specifies. These values inside the function are local variables for it to use, and are initialized to 0 or null (the ambiguity is because awk only decides the type of a variable when a value is assigned to it). Such an arg can also be an array, whose name is private to the function, and the space it takes is released on exit.

Comment: For more information about how to define local variables inside a function, see section 9.2.3.2 (Controlling Variable Scope) of the GNU Awk User’s Guide.